# assign id for table header in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please let me know how to assign id for table header (`th`) with `class="tableHeader"` and table `id="requestview_table"` using javascript(after html table is constructed). Currently, the table headers don't have any id.
[image][image][image]

Please let me know how to insert id (any number) for  with class tableHeader.

Comment: What's the "table header", the `<tr>` with `<th>` cells, the first row, each cell in the first row...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m0sa's answer is cleaner (yeay! jQuery) but if you want a JavaScript only solution then this is my stab at it:

Firstly you need a method to get items based on class name (which is something I modified from here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1143850&page=1).

```
function getElementsByClassName(strClassName, obj) {

    var arrClassElements = [];
    if (obj) {
        if (obj['className'] && obj.className.indexOf(strClassName) != -1) {
            arrClassElements.push(obj);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.childNodes.length; i++) {
            arrClassElements = arrClassElements.concat(getElementsByClassName(strClassName, obj.childNodes[i]));
        }
    }

    return arrClassElements;
}
```

Then you use this to iterate through the elements it picked up, using `setAttribute` to add an ID to the element.

```
var headers = getElementsByClassName('tableHeader', document.getElementById('requestview_table'));

for(var i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
    headers[i].setAttribute('id', 'header' + i) 
    alert(headers[i].id);
}
```

This is it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/W6JyE/

Again, I recommend you **use jQuery if you can**. It's much better and cleaner for doing the type of operations you're looking to do. This is just one of many alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#requestview_table").find("th.tableHeader").each(function(index) { $(this).attr('id','header' + index); });
```